# Can we use usb webcam with picamera?

Tags: python, usb, camera, webcam

Is it possible to use a usb webcam instead of raspberry pi camera module
for picamera?
If yes how?

Comment: Hello, Nishant.  This question is currently overly broad for our site.  If you can edit your question to be more specific, we can help you, but currently we can't really give you a good answer since this isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: I changed the tags here presuming you are referring to the python picamera module.  If you meant something else, you should explain it.  I would guess the answer is no, since the picamera module is probably just a wrapper around the C interface peculiar to the raspicam.  There are surely more generic python interfaces for using cameras, but if you want to ask about that, ask on our larger sibling site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) (where [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711946/how-to-programmatically-capture-a-webcam-photo) should provide some clues).

Comment: If you're asking about the Python picamera library, see http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/faq.html#can-i-use-picamera-with-a-usb-webcam (answer: no)

Comment: @DaveJones - thats probably the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

The Python picamera library is only for the official Raspberry Pi  camera module connected to the CSI bus. If you want to use regular USB Webcams , look at projects supporting V4L2 .

Example :

https://github.com/gebart/python-v4l2capture